# rss crate is installed, but cannot find the function Channel::from_url

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I tried to use the RSS crate in a project. I added `rss = "1.5.0"` to the dependencies in Cargo.toml and built my code:

```
extern crate regex;
extern crate rss;

use rss::Channel;

fn main() {
    let channel = Channel::from_url("https://feedpress.me/usererror.xml");
}
```

When I run cargo build, I have the following error:

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling rss_f v0.1.0 (file:///home/philippe/test/rss_f)
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `from_url` found for type `rss::Channel` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:7:19
  |
7 |     let channel = Channel::from_url("https://feedpress.me/usererror.xml");
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `rss::Channel`
```

When I highlight the function in VScode, I have an error from RLS and at the same time Racer gives me the definition of the function. So the crate is installed but Cargo can't use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you re-read [the documentation](https://docs.rs/rss/1.5.0/rss/index.html), emphasis mine:

> ## From a URL
>
> A channel can also be read from a URL.
>
> **Note: This requires enabling the `from_url` feature**.
>
> ```
> use rss::Channel;
>
> let channel = Channel::from_url("http://example.com/feed.xml").unwrap();
> ```

Thus, you need to enable the feature in your **Cargo.toml**:

```
rss = { version = "1.5.0", features = ["from_url"] }
```